# Converting 2D array to 1D Array without using ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Create Function for Convert 2d array into 1D array**

But at Declaration time the size of 1D array how to give size to the new 1D array

```
int[] convert(int[][] input){
    int[] result;
    int z=0;
    for(int row=0;row<input.length;row++) {
        for(int col=0;col<input[row].length;col++) {
            result[z]=input[row][col];
            z++;
        }
    }
    return result;/* Error comes here For Initialization. How to initialize before Knowing size*/
}
```

Comment: "How to initialize before Knowing size" <- For an array not possible. Just determine the needed size before you initialize your new array.

Comment: You could iterate your 2d array beforehand, then count all lengths of all sub-arrays and add them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if rows and columns are balanced

```
int result[] = new int[input.length * input[0].length];
```

otherwise, you have to loop through the whole array while keeping a count of length

```
int len = 0;
for(int[] a : input){
    len+=a.length;
}
int[] result = new int[len];
```

Comment: Thanks, Pavneet_Singh that's correct.Once again Thanks a lot.

Comment: i am glad that we could help, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compute the size this way (i.e number of *rows* * number of *columns*):

```
int[] result = new int[input.length * input[0].length] ;
```

Comment: This will only work if all sub arrays have the same length, i.e. if the 2d array is rectangular.

Comment: You're right, I was assuming that the 2D array was rectangular (2D meaning 2 dimensions, I wouldn't think that one was fixed and another varying).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Great. It Was working. What if the  both Array have Different Size eg:  int [][]y= {{10,20,30,40},{2,6,8,7,6,9}};

Comment: @DheerajThakur : In that case, see the answer from Pavneet_Singh .

Answer (score 0):

1)If it is rectangular 2D array, compute the size this way

```
int array[]  = new int[input.length * input[0].length];
```

2)If it is not rectangular, iterate through each row and add the length of each sub-array

```
int size = 0;
for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
 size += input[i].length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use streams with out to have to take care of size by yourself:

```
int[] convert(int[][] input){    
    return Stream.of(input).flatMapToInt(x -> Arrays.stream(x)).toArray();
}
```